# Как определить, что remote branch уже удалён?

Tags: git, git-branch

Проблема в следующем:
Я локально создаю репозиторий, вношу какие-то изменения, затем делаю commit и upstream.
Потом он проверяется там другим сотрудником, он делает merge to master и delete branch.
Я локально вывожу список репозиториев:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то, что я выделил красным прямоугольником "сверху" удалено, очень бы хотелось это как-то пометить в данном списке...

в опции --format у нас есть в распоряжении [некоторые поля](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names).

можно ли в них найти информацию о том, что remote branch удалён?

Думал через `%(upstream:track)`, но он пуст в данном случае, как и в неудалённом.

**[added]**: Благодаря подсказке @Alexey Ten, добавил выделение удалённых... Жить стало намного легче)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделать `git fetch --prune`. Тогда `%(upstream:track)` покажет `[gone]`

Comment: @Alexey Ten, класс! Век живи - век учись! Меня этот момент очень напрягал постоянно, благодарю.

Comment: `git branch -vv` также показывает, что удалённая ветка исчезла

Answer (score 3):

По умолчанию Git не удаляет remotes ссылки на ветки, удалённые в репозитории на сервере. Чтобы полностью синхронизировать состояние вашего локального репозитория с тем что на сервере, надо у команды git-fetch затребовать очистку.

```
git fetch --prune
```

Чтобы не повторять эту опцию каждый раз, может быть полезно задать глобальную настройку.

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```